# Daily column allotted to a jounalist

Tags: word-usage

A journalist writes a daily column for a newspaper.  When referring to his daily content, which word should I use:  'columns' or 'column'?

Comment: Just like "I publish a magazine" - even though there are seven issues out.

Comment: Thank you.  Does that mean I use "columns"?

Comment: No, the singular "column" is appropriate. Even though there are several editions of this one column in circulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the singular, *column*, to refer to the regular section alloyed to that journalist. It doesn't matter how many physical columns it spans, nor does it matter how many editions of that column the journalist wrote.

> **column** * noun*
>   2.2 A regular section of a newspaper or magazine devoted to a particular subject or written by a particular person.
>   ‘he has a weekly column in a Sydney newspaper’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/column)

Answer (score 0):

***[Editorial](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/editorial)*** is  used to refer to:

> - an article in a newspaper or other periodical or on a website presenting the opinion of the publisher, writer, or editor.

(Dictionary.com)

You can refer to the journalist's daily editorials on the newspaper.